# How to create series of date range in INFORMATICA using transformations?

Tags: sql, etl, informatica

I have a need to create a report , where some dates are present in the table,however the requirement is the report should consist of every monday for the entire year irrespective of the data unavailability(it`ll show null for those dates) .

How to achieve this logic in Informatica?

Answer (score 1):

you need to use some DB for generate date series. And then join that series with your data to get what you want.

1. for oracle you can get a dummy source from oracle(DUAL). and then in SQ query, you can overwrite using below SQL. for any other RDBMS you should get something like generate series to do this.

```
SELECT
  (to_date('01-05-2015','DD-MM-YYYY') - level + 1) AS dt
FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= (to_date('01-01-2020','DD-MM-YYYY') - to_date('01-01-2040','DD-MM-YYYY') + 1)
```

I assumed your start date is jan-20 and end date is jan-2040. You can change them if you want to. You need to make sure which date range you want to see in report.

2. Then join this SQ using a joiner with your main pipeline. It should be master outer join where above source will be a details source.
   Join condition will be -

```
dt = trunc(dt_from pipeline)
```

3. pull all columns including dt from source #1 into next transformation. Please note all columns from your original pipeline will be null if date doesnt exist in pipeline data.

Your data should look like -

```
dt                   Quantity
05-04-2015 00:00:00  1
04-04-2015 00:00:00  
03-04-2015 00:00:00  6
02-04-2015 00:00:00  9
01-04-2015 00:00:00  28
```